# C# string help?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a function in C# that finds the name of a function in a source file such as

```
function void MyFunc
```

I'm trying to create a substring that starts after "void " and I need to find the length of the name of the function. There will always be a space or a newline after the function name.

```
module MyApplication
[EntryPoint]
function void main
write("a string")
endfunction
endmodule
```

Comment: What language is the text in the file? Can we assume that names follow the same rules as in C#?

Comment: @Troy: I mean what are the rules for the source file? What characters could appear in a valid function name? It doesn't look like C#, so I don't know what assumptions I am allowed to make. For example, can I assume that function names can't contain spaces?

Comment: Oh sorry, It's a custom language I'm creating for now and I'm writing a simple parser for it and yes, no spaces in the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LastIndexOf` to find the last space, and grab the part of the string following to get the function name.  Then use the `Length` property to get the length of the code:

```
var s = "function void MyFunc "; // example string
var s2 = s.Trim(); // remove any extra spaces at the end
var funcName = s2.Substring(s2.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1); // 'MyFunc'
var length = funcName.Length; // 6
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/64IYz

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the function name might have other stuff after it, like a parameter list.

What you want to do is look for the word "void", go past it, find the first non-space character (which is the beginning of the function name), and then go to the next space or end of line.

You can use:

```
const string LookFor = "void "; // note space at end.

string GetFunctionName(string line)
{
    int voidPos = line.IndexOf(LookFor);
    if (voidPos == -1)
        return null;
    int functionStart = voidPos + LookFor.Length;
    int spacePos = line.IndexOf(' ', functionStart);
    if (spacePos == -1)
        spacePos = line.Length;
    return line.Substring(functionStart, spacePos - functionStart);
}
```

Comment: How would I get the line from a big source file? With multiple lines.

Comment: @Tr0y: To read a file line-by-line, look into `File.ReadLines`. As in `foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename))`

Answer (score 0):

That's "crying for using regex". Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(function void ){1,1}(?<functionName>^\w*)");
```

Comment: What does `^\w*` do? Won't that match a line that has no function name? That is, `function void `, with nothing following. Did you instead mean `\w+`?

Answer (score 0):

[Sprache](http://code.google.com/p/sprache/) can do this, but you'd need to write a grammar for the whole file, as it doesn't implement "searching" for a match.

Something along these lines would parse *just the function declaration* - as noted above, to make your scenario work you need to add rules for modules and so on.

```
var identifier = (from first in Parse.Letter
                  from rest in Parse.LetterOrDigit.Many().Text()
                  select first + rest).Token();

var returnType = Parse.String("void").Or(Parse.String("int")).Token();
var functionKeyword = Parse.String("function").Token();
var endFunctionKeyword = Parse.String("endfunction").Token();

var function = from fk in functionKeyword
               from rt in returnType
               from functionName in identifier
               from body in Parse.AnyChar.Until(endFunctionKeyword)
               select functionName;

var name = function.Parse("function void main write(\"a string\") endfunction");
```

The variable `name` above will contain the string `"main"` (unless I've made some typos :))

Sprache is a bit more powerful than regular expressions, but doesn't require any special build-time processing. There are some tutorials on this approach linked from the Sprache homepage.